# Manilpulate multiple ArrayLists with loops

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a large number of ArrayLists, and I want to be able to manipulate them using for loops. If they are named p1, p2, p3 ... pn, how can I perform a task such as .get(0) for all of them using a loop instead of

```
p1.get(0);
p2.get(0);
p3.get(0);
pn.get(0);
```

Comment: The solution is to not do this.  Use an array/collection instead of lots of individual variables.

Comment: Well, you'd need an actual loop first. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Create an arrayList of arrayList's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ListsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> p1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
        List<Integer> p2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
        List<Integer> p3 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
        List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        lists.add(p1);
        lists.add(p2);
        lists.add(p3);

        for(List<Integer> list : lists){
            System.out.println(list.get(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your `ArrayList`s in an `ArrayList`.  Access them in a `for` loop, then call `get(0)` on your retrieved `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You could put them all into a list and loop over them

```
List<ArrayList> lists = new LinkedList<ArrayList>();
lists.add(p1);
lists.add(p2);

for ( ArrayList list : lists ) {
   list.get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. If you mean how to access the four separate arrays in a loop...

```
for (int i = 0; i < ...; ++ i) {
    p1.get(i);
    p2.get(i);
    p3.get(i);
    pn.get(i);
}
```

If you mean you have four equal-sized arrays and you want to group the data together more conveniently, then ditch the four areas, make a class with the relevant fields to store your data in instead, and use a single array of that:

```
class Item {
    Whatever v1;
    Whatever v2;
    Whatever v3;
    Whatever vn;
}

ArrayList<Item> items = ...;
items.get(0);
```

If you mean you have a variable number of those arrays and you want to select which one you access dynamically, you can use an ArrayList of the original ArrayLists:

```
List<ArrayList<Whatever>> p = getListOfAllMyArrayLists();
p.get(n).get(0);
```

If you want to keep all your separate arrays for some reason (maybe you can't refactor) and just want a convenient way to access all the data at once, you can write a method to do that and pack the results into their own array, e.g.:

```
public List<Whatever> getAll (int x) {
    List<Whatever> values = new ArrayList<Whatever>();
    values.add(p1.get(x));
    values.add(p2.get(x));
    values.add(p3.get(x));
    values.add(pn.get(x));
    return values;
}
```

You could also implement `getAll()` to take a variable number of source arrays if you use an ellipses parameter.

I hope one of these is helpful.